# Поясните задачу?

Tags: javascript

подскажите не могу в ловить эту задачу

**Задача**: Объявление переменной myAge и ее значения, например:
const myAge = 20;

Вывод в консоль сообщения: “Мой возраст 21 год”(без кавычек), где “21” - значение переменной myAge (во время проверки оно может быть любым), а окончание “год”, должно зависеть от цифры возраста, например:
21 год, 22 года, 24 года, 25 лет, 19 лет, 20 лет.

Comment: Вывести в консоль сообщение со значением переменной myAge. Что непонятного?

Comment: "не могу в ловить" - что есть "в ловить"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вор решение, если не в ловили:

```js
function getAge (number) {
    if (number >= 5 && number <= 20)
      return 'лет'

    number %= 10

    if (number == 1)
      return 'год'
    if (number >= 2 && number <= 4)
      return 'года'

    return 'лет'
}

// Для вывода результата
for (let age of [1, 2, 12, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30])
  console.log(`Мой возраст ${age} ${getAge(age)}`)
```

Есть еще такой прикольный вариант, как он Вам, пользователи?

```js
function getAge (age) {
  const words = {
    'few': 'года',
    'many': 'лет',
    'one': 'год'
  }
  const key = new Intl.PluralRules().select(age)
  
  return `Мой возраст ${age} ${words[key]}`
}

// Для вывода результата
for (let age of [1, 2, 12, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30])
  console.log(getAge(age))
```

Comment: "Мой возраст 12 года"

Comment: не в ловил в начале тоже

Comment: `Intl.PluralRules("ru")` +1

Answer (score 0):

Склонение по числам на Delphi
*(case - switch, div - целочисленное деление, mod - остаток (%))*

```
//usage: PluralWord(3, "рубль", "рубля", "рублей");
function PluralWord(Amount: Integer; const One, Two, Five: string): string;
begin
 Amount := Abs(Amount);
 case 4 * Ord(1 = (Amount mod 100) div 10) + (Amount - 1) mod 10 of
   0: Result := One;
   1..3: Result := Two;
   else
    Result := Five;
 end;
end;

for i := 1 to 30 do
   Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d %s',[i, PluralWord(i, 'год', 'года', 'лет')]));

...
11 лет
...
19 лет
20 лет
21 год
22 года
23 года
24 года
25 лет
26 лет
```