# Склонение числительных

Tags: php

Помогите сделать php код, который бы отталкиваясь от числа писал правильные окончания к "тем", по типу 1 тема, 2 темы, 11 тем ...

```
<?php
$topic1 = Тема;
$topic2 = Темы;
$topic3 = Тем;

if ($answer == 1 ) {
echo $topic1;
}
elseif ($answer  == 2 or 3 or 4) {
echo $topic2;
}
elseif ($answer == 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12 or 13 or 14 or 15 or 16 or 17 or 18 or 19==20) {
echo $topic3;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Уже реализованно с использованием остатков от деления http://codinghamster.info/php/correct-plural-form-of-a-noun/

Comment: @Ипатьев Указанная тема - не дубликат, вопрос не о том. [Вот похожее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883212/Поясните-задачу/883220#883220) (не php)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю и буду пользоваться.